# gcc template error

Tags: c++, generics, gcc, templates, metaprogramming

why in the first line of this code:

```
template <typename VectorType>
std::string repr_vector_dynamic(const VectorType* vect)
{
    std::stringstream strs;
    strs << "(";
    for (int i = 0; i < vect->size(); ++i) {
        if (0 != i) {
            strs << ", ";
        }
        strs << (*vect)[i];
    }
    strs << ")";
    return strs.str();
}
```

I always get thsese errors at the first line: (MinGW gcc 4.5)

> expected ';' before 'template'
>
> expected primary-expression before 'template'

thx

**later edit**: here is the command line / log I got from eclipse:

```
g++ -II:\proj\bp\PyCML -IC:\PF\Python26\include -II:\proj\bp/include -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -oPyCML\cml.o ..\PyCML\cml.cpp
In file included from I:\proj\bp/include/boost/python/object/make_instance.hpp:9:0,
             from I:\proj\bp/include/boost/python/object/make_ptr_instance.hpp:8,
             from I:\proj\bp/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:11,
             from I:\proj\bp/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from I:\proj\bp/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from I:\proj\bp/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:14,
             from I:\proj\bp/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from I:\proj\bp/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from ..\PyCML\cml.cpp:11:
I:\proj\bp/include/boost/python/object/instance.hpp:14:36: warning: type attributes ignored after type is already defined
In file included from ..\PyCML\cml.cpp:28:0:
I:\proj\bp\PyCML/PyCMl/vector.h: In function 'void init_module_PyCML()':
I:\proj\bp\PyCML/PyCMl/vector.h:22:1: error: expected primary-expression before 'template'
I:\proj\bp\PyCML/PyCMl/vector.h:22:1: error: expected ';' before 'template'
..\PyCML\cml.cpp:58:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
```

Comment: What is **before** `template` in your code?  Did you perhaps forget to put the `;` at the end of a class declaration immediately before this function template?

Comment: there are only includes from other libraries

Comment: What happens if you add another declaration before your template? Ie a "void funcdecl(void);" will that cause an error before your template or a missing semicolon before the dummy declaration?

Comment: it changes nothing, no extra error, nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors that you have posted suggest that the problem is within the function `void init_module_PyCML()`. It would therefore appear that you have tried to define a function template within the body of another function.

For example trying to compile the following code gives me the same error

```
void f()
{

template < typename T >
void g()
{
};

}
```

The last error line suggests that perhaps you have forgotten the closing `}` for `init_module_PyCML()`?

Comment: you might have the right answer, in my mind BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE was leaving between the braces the scope of a namespace, so I included these headers in that, so far I get 96 boost::python errors, but I think it's a start

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, it is what comes *before* the `template` declaration that is missing the `;`.

Take a look at what the compiler sees, thus:

`g++ -E <yourfile>.cpp | less`

Comment: I tried your idea, I had to remove all of the includes because the file was getting too long:

g++ -E vector.h /* mine's a header file */ -I<include paths> > test.txt

but like I said before, preceding the template are only includes:

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <typename VectorType>
std::string repr_vector_dynamic(const VectorType* vect)
{

Comment: @lj8888: The point is you need to see what the headers have expanded to after preprocessing so you musn't remove anything otherwise you invalidate this particular test. Also, don't run this on the header file, just run it on the source file that won't compile. Rather than `| less` you can just redirect it to a file using `> yourfile.ii` if you want. You can then search through that file using your favourite text editor to find your `repr_vector_dynamic` function template and see _exactly_ what is on the preceding lines now that all headers and macros have been replaced with actual content.

Comment: if I run it on the .cpp file I only get the g++ errors, that I added in the edit, if I run the -E on the header, the file size is huge, adn repr_vector_dynamic cannot by found by searching

Answer (score 0):

```
expected ';' before 'template'
expected primary-expression before 'template'
```

You forgot a semicolon before the first line. Can you give the previous line ?

Comment: like I said, there are only includes, but here you go:

#include <PyCML/PyCML.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;
using namespace cml;

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <typename VectorType>
std::string repr_vector_dynamic(const VectorType* vect)

Comment: there are no missing ';' before this

Comment: Can you give the command line you used ? Is it the only file ?

Comment: there are more files, I am building with eclipse, I guess I can extract the command line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be using `g++`, the C++ compiler, instead of `gcc`, the C compiler.

Another possibility is that one of your headers has `#define`d a truly evil macro.

Comment: gcc will run in C++ mode if the file has a C++ extension.  And if this was actually compiled as C, you'll get a much different error.